# Hiding an element with hide() causes a page "jump"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an effect where I display a big logo on page load. When the user scrolls pass the logo and navigation, I want to display a fixed nav bar with a smaller logo. I then want to hide the big logo so that **when the user scrolls to the top they still see the fixed nav bar (i.e. the big logo and original navigation stay hidden).**

However, when I remove a big block element with the `.hide()` property it causes the page to "jump" as the display:none property gets set. This reduces the usability of the page, as the location jumps the size of the element that was removed, potentially confusing users.

Is there a way I can get the effect I want, while still providing a smooth experience to the user? I've been thinking of potential options, but have been drawing blanks. Hoping you guys can inspire me :)

A simple JS fiddle can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/darudude/vA5WG/ (Note: You'll have to increase the result section to 720+px to get it to work properly - I'm still working on the responsive part)

The code in question:

```
function UpdateTableHeaders() {

    var menu       = $(".main_nav_menu"),
    offset_top     = menu.offset().top;

    var scrollTop  = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > (offset_top + menu.height()))
    {
        $(".clone").addClass("floating_header");
        $(".big_logo").hide();
    }
}
$(window).scroll(function(){
    UpdateTableHeaders();
});
```

Comment: try setting opacity to 0 instead of hide...

Comment: That is the equivalent of visibility:hidden which is not the affect I want - I dont want the white space at the top when the user scrolls up

Comment: Just set your logo to position absolute or fixed from the begining, it won't be in the flow so hiding it won't be changing the flow... i'm on iPad right now though so it's hard for me to come with a nice example.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this ,

Add a new style

```
<style>
        .hide {
   position: absolute !important;
   top: -9999px !important;
   left: -9999px !important;
}
</style>
```

**And change your JS to**

```
$(".big_logo").addClass('hide');

Instead of 

$(".big_logo").hide();
```

Comment: Was using display: none and display: block but there was a page jump. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `visibility:hidden` then

```
$(".big_logo").css('visibility','hidden');
```

Comment: I cant use hidden - I'll have a big whitespace when they scroll to the top.

Comment: When they scroll back to the top, the normal header should reappear, no?

Comment: Nope - I want it so when the scroll back the fixed header stays, and the normal header and bigger logo stay gone

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is because a different browser - margin/padding thing. Have you tried to add this to the body element (or to the container element if it inherits some margins/paddings)

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
```